# Xpages large number of documents values in repeat control

Tags: xpages, document, repeat, xpages-ssjs

I am working on the application where which we need to migrate from old notes application to xpages. So from the old application we have more than 2,00,000 Documents.

So in an xpages application we are loading these list of documents with the help of repeat control, So is there any optimized way to load data faster because loading this much amount of Documents take more than 5 min to load.

Some kind of sugestions would be really helpful.

The formula for the repeat control from which I loads data is from page data source dominoView. The page datasource is :>

[image]

And this data source is used in a repeat control to load dynamically as in image.

[image]

We also have pager and limited rows mentioned to repeat.

Comment: I would definitely avoid loading that many documents at a time if you can.  What’s the use case for having 200,000 documents on screen at once?  You can add a pager control to the repeat to page the documents up at say 30 at a time.

Comment: Yes you are right but we already have a pager with limit of 20 entries , but dont know it loads all the document at a time. And then also pager occurs.

Comment: I think the problem is not the repeat itself, but the way you get the collection. What is your repeat "value" formula?

Comment: Ok , i quicky edit my question and post some more details on the repeat formula . Please have a look and if its all going correct or not please.

Comment: any computation in the view selection formula and columns? avoid any computation at runtime. I mostly use repeat controls with arraylists of java objects or javasjonobjects then I can just inject the object values in the repeat control items. I do not have so large record sets but tens of thousands documents right fine, even on mobile via telephone provider.

Answer (score 1):

You need to redesign your approach. For starters don't try to load documents, but load viewEntries. Scanning through a view is substantially faster than opening each document.

Secondly: I'd suggest you go for a client side (non repeat control) based approach: Use one of the datagrids that feed on Json with virtual loading. That should make a better user experience.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in your screenshot: it shows that row's `styleClass` property calls `rowData.getDocument()`. That' a big no-no, especially if you use this trick in many places of the repeat content.

Update your view and put anything useful for page rendering to view's columns. That's what @stwissel said, anyway.

Comment: yes I got it , not only for styleClass but I am also using rowData.getDocument() for retrieving document fields in repeat list.I understand that now that I am requesting the document from server for every field value which is taking time to load. As I have this working code many other applications, as but only this application I faced the issue and now redesigning may creates the risk, So is there any safe solution to get data from document instead of calling rowData.getDocument() for the every data inside the document field?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to rethink your design. How can a user find something in 2M docs? Maybe put some other filters or searching in front of the repeat?

Comment: Yes , we have a search bar but at the time of loading at first time it loads all the documents first and then the searching works.

Comment: As I said, you need to rethink your logic. Let the user enter a search term first and then display the results only. Have some way to filter the documents... Something... What good is having a repeat with 2M docs? There is no way anyone is going to go through these page by page.

Comment: As Howard says, reverse your logic. Load no documents initially, then load them based on the search. Or load 25 only for a start. There's a reason Google and other websites load a restricted data set, and the performance proves it. If you want to simulate a Notes view on the web use a client-side approach lazy-loading as the user scrolls down. But I would strongly advise against an architecture from a premise of reproducing Notes Client on web, because that's not how browser apps work.